# How to show thumbnail images on product pages using ubercart module?

Tags: 7, media, ubercart

I recently installed a test of Drupal/Ubercart on one of my test servers. I added a test product and uploaded 3 pictures for the product. My problem is that the 3 pictures are displayed in Full Size on every page that the product is listed. How do I enable thumbnails for these product images? I am quite sure that I have all modules that are required installed, but I see no place to enable thumbnails on product pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly go to *[your-domain]/admin/config/media/image-styles* and create image style you want to use for your product images, than go to *[your-domain]/admin/structure/types* and click on 'manage display' on the right (for content type that you are using for products).

You will find your image field whose format is probably 'Image' and you will see a little gear on the right, click on it and for 'Image style' choose image style that you created previously (as mentioned above).

That's it. Now the images will be shown according to image style that you created.

For the list of the product I recommend that you use [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module and again to control your display image size by choosing image style for image field in Views.